# how to put Windows pc to sleep after specific time

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, sleep

I know that we can shut down windows after some specific time like this

```
shutdown -s -t <time>
```

But how can I do the same when I want my pc to sleep after some specific amount of time?? is there any command??

Also it will be helpful if you told me the command for Linux too, Cause i rarely use windows.

Comment: Are you looking to put the PC to sleep after say, 15 minutes or are you looking to put it to sleep at a particular time (say, 3:30PM)

Comment: I’m rather puzzled by the close votes.  This question asks how to put the PC to sleep ***after a delay*** for Windows and ideally also for Linux.  That question is about how to put the PC to sleep ***right now*** for Windows only.   Overlap?  Yes.  Duplicate?  No.

Comment: @G-Man the marked answer in the other question mentions the method discussed here.

Comment: @Burgi: What are you talking about? I read the linked question last week when I wrote the above comment; I read the *accepted* answer (I assume that’s what you mean by “the marked answer”) again, three times, just now. Yes, it discusses the `rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0` command, which is mentioned here (and yes, I deliberately switched the verbs), and which answers that question. And, as I said in my comment, the other question is about one-quarter of this question, and so its answer is one-quarter of an answer to this question. So what’s your point?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the Linux solution, on recent systems:

```
systemctl suspend
systemctl hibernate
```

If you want this to happen after a delay, combine with the sleep command:

```
sleep 1h 30m && systemctl suspend
```

You can also use the `kshutdown` utility that gives you a GUI to shutdown/sleep on various conditions: after some delay, at a specific time, or when some process terminates.